# Vuex getters not returning the data

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, store, vuejs3

I have a Vuex getters that return the state of `courseData` but for some reason, I couldn't access it. I tried to do `console.log(this.$store.getters)` and the getter that I am trying to access is present and has values. But when I try to do `console.log(this.$store.getters.getCourseData)` or `console.log(this.$store.getters['courses/getCourseData'])` it returns an empty array instead of an object.

**Component:**

```
<script>
import { mapActions, mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      data: null,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions('courses', ['fetchCourseData']),
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters('courses', ['getCourseData'])
  },
  created() {
    this.fetchCourseData(this.$route.params.code) // <-- This line sets the state
    console.log(this.$store.getters) // <-- List of store getters
    console.log(this.$store.getters['courses/getCourseData']) // <-- Returns empty array
    console.log(this.$store.getters.getCourseData) // <-- Returns undefined
  }
}
</script>
```

**Store:**

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    courseData: [],
  },
  getters: {
    getCourseData(state) {
      return state.courseData
    }
  },
  actions: {
    async fetchCourseData({ commit }, code) {
      await axios
        .get('teacher/course-management/course/code/' + code)
        .then(response => {
          commit('SET_COURSE_DATA', response.data.data)
        })
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_COURSE_DATA(state, courseData) {
      state.courseData = courseData
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: courseData is assigned asynchronously. You try to access it immediately. getters.getCourseData is a mistake because it's namespaced

Comment: I tried to do it synchronously just to test it out and the issue still persists.
I tried to add setTimeOut() method on retrieving the getters and it is still the same.

Comment: You tested it the wrong way. You need to await for the action. With promises. And obviously it won't succeed if the state failed to update.

Comment: The state is updating okay my main problem is I can not retrieve the value of the getter. Even in my chrome Vue.js devtools the getter and data values are okay.

Comment: Then the problem is that you access a getter at the wrong moment.

Comment: try ```this.fetchCourseData(this.$route.params.code).then(()=>{ console.log(this.$store.getters['courses/getCourseData']) })```

Answer (score 1):

Since you already use `async/await` in your action, also use it on your `created` method.

```js
async created() {
    await this.fetchCourseData(this.$route.params.code) // <-- This line sets the state
    console.log(this.$store.getters) // <-- List of store getters
    console.log(this.$store.getters['courses/getCourseData']) // <-- Returns empty array
    console.log(this.$store.getters.getCourseData) // <-- Returns undefined
  }
```